# Zero Knowledge Interactive Proof vs zero knowledge proof

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

What is the difference between Zero Knowledge Interactive Proof and zero knowledge proof?

Nathan Aw

Answer (score 0):

Zero knowledge proof can be divided into interactive zero knowledge proof and non-interactive zero knowledge proof.

Besides, there is already a way to convert from interactive to non-interactive.

Comment: If random oracles exist, the Fiat-Shamir heuristic is secure to convert an interactive proof to a non-interactive proof.

Comment: @YoussefElHousni "If random oracles exist" Well, they don't. :)

Comment: It is NOT true that interactive can be converted to non-interactive. In particular, we know how to construct ZK for all NP from one-way functions only, but we need one-way (or trapdoor) permutations for non-interactive zero-knowledge. (In the random oracle, things are indeed different).